# ASP.NET MVC source code missing solution file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I recently inherited some source code developed by someone else who is no longer with the company. However, the solution file was missing and I'm not even sure which version of MVC it was using. I'm experienced with ASP.NET, but not well-versed in MVC so I'm unsure how to go about rebuilding the solution the proper way. Looking for any tips/guidance on how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new, blank solution.
2. Open the solution in Windows Explorer.
3. Copy the project files into the solution folder.
4. Within Visual Studio, right-click the solution in Solution Explorer, and then chose the option to *Add Existing Project...*.
5. Navigate to the solution folder (if necessary), and then select the .csproj (or .vbproj) file. The project will added into the solution.

Now, whether you can compile the solution/project depends on whether the version of MVC is compatible with the tooling installed in your instance of Visual Studio. If the project has NuGet dependencies, they should be restored the first time you build, depending (again) on your version of Visual Studio and tooling.

**Edited:**

Since you say that even the project file is missing, you can, assuming there are no external dependencies, create a new MVC project and then copy/paste the files into it (or drag & drop the files from Windows Explorer). Assuming there is a Views folder, it will have it's own web.config file. *That* config file will have bindings for the version of MVC the project was developed with.

MVC4 and newer projects tended to default to using Razor syntax, so the views will be littered with stuff like `@Model`. If it's using the older WebForms syntax (like `<asp:ContentPlaceholder>`), it's probably MVC3 or older.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no project file either.

Answer (score 1):

Go to web.config file in the project and look for:

```
    assembly="System.Web.Mvc,Version=3.0.0.0 ..."
```

In this example is.MVC 3, look for your version

Comment: The only assembly= reference I found in the file is for Entity Framework. Under appSettings, however, I did find this:

<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />

But apparently this just refers to the version of the Razor engine.